# Parsing Numbers from a File and using those to calculate

Tags: bash, sed, bc

I seem to be to stupid to parse some HTML Files with Bash. We have some files which have lines like:

```
var A4_total = 2018 + 4730;
var Other1_total = 3242 + 3828;
```

(They tell us how many pages the Printers have printed).
I need to calculate the first two Values together (2018 and 3242). My Approach is:

```
hilfsvar1=$(echo `grep -F var\ A4_total StatCntMedia.htm | sed 's/var\ A4\_total\ \=\ //g'` | sed -ne "s/^[^=]\++//p"  | sed 's/;//g'); hilfsvar2=$(echo `grep -F var\ Other1_total StatCntMedia.htm | sed 's/var\ Other1\_total\ \=\ //g'` | sed -ne "s/^[^=]\++//p"  | sed 's/;//g'); echo "$hilfsvar1 + $hilfsvar2" | bc
```

This will fail. The two variables do have the right content:

```
[User]# echo $hilfsvar1
4730
[User]# echo $hilfsvar2
3828
```

But this is where I can't get forward:

```
[User]# echo "$hilfsvar1 + $hilfsvar2"
 +  3828
```

(Sorry for my scripting, I don't have deeper knowlede of Script languages :) ) - I would be happy to resolve this in another way if someone does have a solution.

Thanks in advance, Jonas

Comment: Your command works here, maybe your file has more spaces than you show in the question?

Comment: The correct English isn't `to stupid`, it's `too stupid` :-).

Comment: I'd like to upvote that but it seems I'm too stupid :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this might be what you're looking for:

```
$ awk '{sum[4]+=$4; sum[6]+=$6} END{print sum[4], sum[6]}' file
5260 8558
```

If not, update your question to show expected output.

It seems like you're probably on completely the wrong track though and trying to do somethign in shell that should be done entirely in awk.

Comment: This is Perfect, thank you! I will try to understand what exactly happens there :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
awk '/A4_total|Other1_total/ {print $4+$6}' StatCntMedia.htm 
Output:
6748
7070
```

search for either A4_total or Other1_total, add 4th and 6th field separated by space and display the output.

Comment: Bit shorter `awk '/(A4|Other1)_total/{print $4+$6}'`

Comment: While this works I seem to be too stupid to add those two :/. [User]# awk '/(A4|Other1)_total/{print $4+$6}' StatCntMedia.htm |grep -xv "0" |bc
6748
7070

Comment: Hi, i'm trying to add the first fild of A4_total with the first field of Other1_total and the second with the second. (Wich would be 2018+3242 and 4730+3828. Thanks for all your help! :)

Comment: so how many times these patterns appearing your file? And i would suggest you to close this question and ask a new question as this is a follow up question.

Comment: @almasshaikh: This is what he originally asked for, although it could be clearer.